# iPhone OUTBOX like table design

Tags: iphone

I would like to do a design similar to iPhone outbox.

It displays 3 lines of text in a single column. The first line is large and bold, the second line is of normal size and font and third one is grey color.

Also a time is displayed in the first line with a different font color.

I know to create a two line display using subtitle cell type but i am not sure how the outbox design is achieved.

Have they used a custom view with different labels and put that view inside the cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Create three custom labels and add them as subview to the cell.
You can either do that directly in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or by subclassing UITableViewCell. Alternatively, you can design your custom cell in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try creating a custom cell interface and come back with my experince.